# Wicket: Is using PropertyResolver ok?

Tags: java, wicket

I have an object and in several components I need to render two of its properties concatenated together with a delimiter.   If one of the properties is null then it should not display the delimiter but just the not null property.   If both are null then it should not display at all.

The two properties are accessed thus:

```
thing.getFoo()
```

and

```
thing.getStuff().getBar()
```

The renderer will be a class with one static method taking an instance of the type of thing and will return a string.

The problem is that it seems ugly to do so much null checking on thing and the result of thing.getStuff() so I was wondering if to use PropertyResolver instead.

The problem is that the [Javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/lang/PropertyResolver.html) says it's not part of the Wicket API and to only use it if I know what I'm doing.   I presume therefore that there are certain caveats or issues that I should know about?   If so, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom read only model in that case. Something like:

```
private static class ConcatenatingPropertyModel extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<String> {

    private List<PropertyModel<String>> models = new ArrayList<PropertyModel<String>>();

    public ConcatenatingPropertyModel(Object object, String... props) {
        for (String prop : props) {
            models.add(new PropertyModel<String>(object, prop));
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public String getObject() {
        // iterate over delegate property models and concatenate
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        super.detach();
        for (PropertyModel<String> model : models) {
            model.detach();
        }    
    }
}
```

Then you can use the model like this:

```
new ConcatenatingPropertyModel(thing, "foo", "stuff.bar");
```